# best practise for logging on Elastic Map Reduce - AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, spark-streaming, amazon-emr

I am planning to use Amazon EMR for spark streaming application. Amazon provides a nice interface to show stderr & controller log. But for streaming application I am not sure how manage the logs.

Amazon logs the data to `/var/log/hadoop/steps/<step-id>` and similar places for spark. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-manage-view-web-log-files.html

I was wondering on how do we rotate logs and still be accessible via the aws emr web interface. We can easily change the log rotation policy by configuring the hadoop-log4j, but that way I cannot access it via the web interface. Also EMR should manage the log s3 upload

Comment: Did you got an answer for rotate logs in EMR?

Answer (score -2):

AWS EMR also stores the logs in S3.

Navigate to your cluster console for the running cluster, and in the left middle column, you'll see the path to the s3 bucket.

Be careful not to reuse the same s3 bucket path for future clusters, otherwise you could overwrite your log data.

Comment: I am aware that EMR uploads log to S3, My question is how do you manage it as it keeps growing ? how do you rollover/rotate them

Comment: your question is confusing because: EC2 nodes within EMR are terminated when the cluster is terminated, meaning that there is only remaining log data in s3 buckets. So, because you can still view the details of a cluster after a cluster is terminated, that would point to the strong possibility that the UI is being populated by the s3-stored log data. And S3 bucket objects can have expiration rules applied to them. That would serve as a simple rotation method for the s3 based files...so, naturally, now I'm wondering how much log data do you expect to generate? is it cost youre concerned about?